# Limits of ${\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^x\mathrm{d}x}$ changed to $(0,\infty)$ if $f(x)$ is even

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponentiation, even-and-odd-functions

In a medical imaging paper the following integral is changed from:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^x\mathrm{d}x$$
To:
$$\int_0^\infty2f(x)\cosh(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I understand how you could get $2f(x)$ without the exponential but I don't get how one can deal with the exponentials without assuming they are a constant wrt $x$ that can be moved outside the integral and back in afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Hint:

$\cosh(x)=\dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$

Comment: Oh ok I got it. I knew that I just didn't do a change of variables: 
Separate into two integrals with 0 to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ limits
Change variables ($x$ to $-x$) and order of limits in second integral
Group into one integral and factor out a 2